# Update Managed Objects in Managed Object Context After Batch Update

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ios8

When you execute a batch update using the `NSBatchUpdateRequest` class available since iOS 8, any existing managed object contexts aren't aware of the changes made to the persistent store. My question is how to update the managed object context to reflect the changes in the persistent store.

I'm using a fetched results controller and I've tried turning every managed object into a fault by calling `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` on the managed object context and reloading the table view, but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An NSBatchUpdateRequest can be set to have a result type of `NSStatusOnlyResultType`, `NSUpdatedObjectIDsResultType`, or `NSUpdatedObjectsCountResultType`. The `NSUpdatedObjectIDsResultType` is the only one that returns meaningful information about what objects were affected by the batch operation.

With the object IDs you can inform your context that it needs to refresh these objects. Any fetched results controllers observing the context will see the change notification and act accordingly.

Example: How to Fire EVERYONE.

```
[context performBlock:^{
    NSError                 *batchError     = nil;
    NSBatchUpdateRequest    *batchRequest   = nil;
    NSBatchUpdateResult     *batchResult    = nil;

    batchRequest = [NSBatchUpdateRequest batchUpdateRequestWithEntityName:@"Employee"];
    [batchRequest setPropertiesToUpdate:@{@"employed" : @NO}];
    [batchRequest setPredicate:nil];
    [batchRequest setAffectedStores:[[context persistentStoreCoordinator] persistentStores] ];
    [batchRequest setResultType:NSUpdatedObjectIDsResultType];
    batchResult = (NSBatchUpdateResult *)[context executeRequest:batchRequest error:&batchError];

    if ([[batchResult result] respondsToSelector:@selector(count)]){
        if ([[batchResult result] count] > 0){
            [context performBlock:^{
                for (NSManagedObjectID *objectID in [batchResult result]){
                    NSError         *faultError = nil;
                    NSManagedObject *object     = [context existingObjectWithID:objectID error:&faultError];
                    // Observers of this context will be notified to refresh this object.
                    // If it was deleted, well.... not so much.
                    [context refreshObject:object mergeChanges:YES];
                }
            }];
        } else {
            // We got back nothing!
        }
    } else {
        // We got back something other than a collection
    }
}];
```

Obviously, there are a lot of scenarios where this will not meet your needs, or will simply not work. You may have to refresh quite a few contexts - recursively performing the refresh block on a chain of contexts does work, but will be unaware of any contexts that are siblings (yet another reason to avoid creating siblings).

Comment: I tried this approach earlier, but it didn't work for me. The batch update is successful, but the managed object context doesn't pull in the changes. Have you tested your solution?

Comment: I have. Make sure it's the root context, and all objects  are faults

Comment: The problem seems to be that the managed object context uses cached data. I only got it to work by setting the managed object context's `stalnessInterval` property to `0.0`. This isn't ideal. Is there a way to bypass the managed object context's cache or delete it?

Comment: You seem to misunderstand. You should use the root context and ensure all objects as faults. Objects that are not faults *are the in memory representation*. If the context has an in-memory copy of an object, it will use it. If it is a child context, it will pull the object from it's parent. Fault the objects. Faulting is a fundamental concept in Core Data.

Comment: I'm familiar with faulting. The problem, however, turned out to be the fetched results controller. After turning the managed objects into faults, you need to call `performFetch:` on the fetched results controller.

Comment: Why do you need second "performBlock"?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSBatchUpdateResult*)executeBatchUpdateRequest:(NSBatchUpdateRequest*)request
                                          context:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context
                                            error:(NSError**)error{
    NSBatchUpdateResult *bur = (NSBatchUpdateResult *)[context executeRequest:request error:error];
    if (bur && bur.resultType == NSUpdatedObjectIDsResultType){
        NSArray <NSManagedObjectID*> *arr = bur.result;
        if ([arr isKindOfClass:NSArray.class] && arr.count > 0){
            // can update multiple contexts
            [NSManagedObjectContext mergeChangesFromRemoteContextSave:@{NSUpdatedObjectsKey:arr}
                                                         intoContexts:@[context]];
    }
    return bur;
}
```

}